# What would be the output of this program and how?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        int x=011;
        System.out.println(x+1);                                 
      }
    }
```

What would be the output of this program and how??

Comment: Why didn't you try it?

Comment: What output you got when you run?

Answer (score 1):

`int x = 011;`

That value is written in *octal notation* and represents the decimal value: 9.
It will print the number 10.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this from [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> An integer literal may be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8), or binary (base 2).
>
> A binary numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters **0b** or **0B** followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 or 1 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit **0** followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> A hexadecimal numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters **0x** or **0X** followed by one or more ASCII hexadecimal digits interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer

So, for your program, it is written is `octal`:

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args){
          int a = 000;
          int b = 001;
          int c = 010;
          int d = 011;

          int x=011;

        System.out.println(a + "\n");
        System.out.println(b + "\n");
        System.out.println(c + "\n");
        System.out.println(d + "\n");
        System.out.println(x+1);                                 
      }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0

1

8

9

10
```

**Explanation :**

011 = 0*8^2+1*8^1+1*8^0 = 0+8+1 = 9.

Since you incremented, it will display `10`.

Answer (score 0):

`011` is 9 is octal base. Therefore x+1 is 10.